# Escape double quotes while writing a JSON file using Unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I have an input file "test.html" with following content.

```
Hi "Alice"
```

And a shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
var=`sed -e 's/"/\\"/g' < test.html`
echo { \"content\": \"$var\" } >> test.json
```

And when I run the above shell script with command

```
>./to-json.sh
```

I am getting the output

```
{ "content": "Hi "Alice"" }
```

While the desired output is (a valid JSON)

```
{ "content": "Hi \"Alice\"" }
```

Can someone please help me identifying what I am doing wrong? How can I get the above desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a real JSON-generation toolkit, such as [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

```sh
var='Hi "Alice"'  ## or var=$(<test.html) to read from a file
jq -nc --arg content "$var" '{ "content": $content }'
```

...properly emits as output:

```
{"content":"Hi \"Alice\""}
```

Comment: (Marking community wiki to avoid harvesting rep from answering a known dupe)

Comment: Thank you. This solution worked on complex html input also.